# Balls covariance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, covariance

A bag contains 52 balls: 13 red, 13 blue, 13 green and 13 yellow. I draw 5 balls without replacement. $X$ is the number of red balls I have drawn and $Y$ is the number of blue balls I have drawn. What is $Cov(X,Y)$?

I first want to compute $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ and my idea is to express $X$ and $Y$ as sums of 5 indicators, where each indicator represents whether the $i$th ball is red/blue, that is $X = \sum_{i=1}^{5} 1$(the $i$th ball is red) and $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{5} 1$(the $i$th ball is blue). Is that a good idea? However, I don't know how to compute the probability of each indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the way to go.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator that ball $i$ is red, and $Y_i$ the indicator that it is blue.  Thus:

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i\\Y=\sum_{i=1}^5 Y_i$$

The expectation of $X_i$, which is also the marginal probability that ball $i$ is red, when each of the $52$ balls are equally probable to be that ball and $13$ among them are red, is clearly:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_i) &= \mathsf P(X_i=1) \\& = \dfrac{13}{52}&&=\dfrac 14\end{align}$$

Likewise $\mathsf E(Y_i) = 1/4$ too.

Obviously a single ball cannot be both red and blue, so $\mathsf E(X_i Y_i)=0$.

Now, all you need is $\mathsf E(X_iY_j)$ when $i\neq j$.  The joint probability that ball $i$ is red and ball $j$ is blue.

Then use the formula for covariance ...

Comment: Thanks so much, @Graham Kemp. Since we are sampling without replacement, could you explain why all $Pr(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$. I can see why it is the case for $X_1$ but then why shouldn't we take into account for $X_2, X_3, ...$ that some balls have already been sampled?

Comment: @RobertLeopold Take a well-shuffled standard pack of $52$ playing cards.  Count and discard twenty cards *without looking at any of them*.  What is the probability that the next card is a heart?

Comment: @RobertLeopold Recall also the Law of Total Probability.  $$\begin{align}\Pr(X_2=1) & =\Pr(X_1=0,X_2=1)+\Pr(X_1=1,X_2=1)\\&= \dfrac{39}{52}\cdotp\!\dfrac{13}{51}+\dfrac{13}{52}\cdotp\!\dfrac{12}{51}\\&=\dfrac 14\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, I get it with the LOTP! Thanks, I am very appreciative of your help.

Comment: continuing the answer, I get $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{5}{4}$. Could you help on how to get $\mathbb{E}[XY]$? I see what you wrote about it but not sure how to get a formula for it.

Comment: $5/4$ is correct.  $\mathsf E(XY)$ is found by:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(XY) &= \mathsf E\!\left(\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i\sum_{j=1}^5 Y_j\right)\\[1ex]&=\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^5~\mathsf P(X_i=1,Y_j=1)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I used linearity of expectation and found $\mathbb{E}(XY)=20 \frac{13*13}{52*51}$